# Http Post, with bearer token, is not working in Bot composer

Tags: botframework, http-post

[Composer Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWQv4.png)
[Composer Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqsGp.png)
We are getting this error while calling HTTP POst call, from Bot Composer, to one of the API. The same call works with Postman.

“statusCode”:401,“reasonPhrase”:“Unauthorized”,“content”:{“error”:{“message”:“User Not Authenticated”,“detail”:“Required to provide Auth information”},“status”:“failure”}}

We tried passing the token without the word "bearer" or with it but we keep getting the below error

“statusCode”:401,“reasonPhrase”:“Unauthorized”,“content”:{“error”:{“message”:“User Not Authenticated”,“detail”:“Required to provide Auth information”},“status”:“failure”}}